Goddess Lakshmi reborn with an elephant face?
I was going through the Skanda Puran where I came across an interesting story related to the curse of Lakshmi to a girl and the resultant curse of that girl's father on Lakshmi to be born with an elephant face.

Due to child-like innocence the blameless beautiful girl sat at the end of the bed to the right of the Enemy of Mura. Thereat, Lakṣmī who had the status of the chief queen became extremely furious thinking her to be her co-wife and cursed the girl: “Since, verily in my very presence, O sinful girl, you set aside all bashfulness and joyously took your seat on the bed of my husband, you will become a hideous Aśvamukhī (Horse-faced).”


When the curse was thus uttered by Śrī, there was a great hue and cry among all those present there. The Brāhmaṇa became angry and said: A thousand persons have been requested on behalf of the girl. Not even a single one among them has accepted her even verbally, let alone grasping her hand. How can she have the status of a wife? As long as she has not been handed over with a prior resolve, in accordance with the injunctions of the Gṛhyasūtras and in the presence of the holy fire, Brāhmaṇas and elders (she has no status of a wife). Hence she is blemishless. But you regarding her on a par with your co-wife, have made her horse-faced. O sinful one, you will also be elephant-faced.

While the first part of the story comes to a happy conclusion by Lord Vishnu's intervention resulting in the girl being born as His sister Subhadra, I am more interested in knowing about the elephant-faced incarnation of Ma Lakshmi.
Is this form of the goddess mentioned in more detail in any other texts?
